# How to complete the following proof of Bolzano's Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove [Bolzano's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) using the following argument. But the problem actually is that though "intuitively" I can "see" why the argument works (if I am not wrong in "seeing"), I can't write down a rigorous proof. The argument is as follows,

> **Bolzano's Theorem**
>
> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that $f(a)<0$ and $f(b)>0$ then, $$\exists c\in(a,b)\mid f(c)=0$$
>
> ***Incomplete Proof.*** Let us consider the sets, $$S^+:=\{f(x):f(x)>0\}$$$$S^-:=\{f(x):f(x)<0\}$$If possible let us assume the negation of the proposition, i.e., for all $ c\in(a,b)$ we have $f(c)\ne 0$.
>
> Since $f$ is a function from a closed and bounded set, we can claim that both the sets $S^+$ and $S^-$ are bounded. So $\inf S^+$ and $\sup S^-$ both exists. Now construct a sequence $\bigl(f(x_n)\bigr)_{n\ge1}$ from $S^+$ such that, $$\inf S^++\dfrac{1}{n}>f(x_n)\ge\inf S^+$$Since $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a bounded sequence so there exists a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ of $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$. Let $(x_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ converge to $x_0$. Due to the continuity of $f$ we can say that $\bigl(f(x_{n_k})\bigr)_{k\ge1}$ converge to $f(x_0)$ which is nothing but $\inf S^+$.
>
> Also, since $f(x_{n_k})>0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we can say that $f(x_0)\ge0$. But by our hypothesis $f(x)\ne0$ and so $f(x_0)>0$. Hence $f(x_0)\in S^+$.
>
> Similarly it can be shown that for some $y_0\in [a,b]$ we have $\sup S^-=f(y_0)<0$.

After this, I can't proceed. The geometric intuition behind the proof was (in very brief) as follows,

> Imagine a continuous function $f$ that *does not* satisfy Bolzano's Theorem. Then there will be a gap between the points $(x_0,f(x_0))$ and $(y_0,f(y_0))$.

$\color{crimson}{\text{Note that I am not looking for a proof of Bolzano's theorem.}}$ Specifically, I just want suggestions for completing this proof (if possible).

Comment: You have the right idea in defining $S^-$. Assert that since $S^-$ is bounded and $\mathbb R$ has the least upper bound property we can find  $c\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x)\lt 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,c)$ and that $c$ is the least upper bound of that half open interval. Then you should be able to show that if $f(c)\ne 0$ then it can't be the least upper bound as originally asserted.

Comment: @JohnDouma: The argument you are giving seems to work well if $S^-:=\{x:f(x)<0\}$. I don't immediately see how it works well for $S^-:=\{f(x):f(x)<0\}$ also. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: You want to use the first form, not the second. I didn't notice that you used the second form in your question. After all, you are looking for an $x$ value.

Comment: @JohnDouma: No. That's the point. The proofs of Bolzano's Theorem that I came to know so far use the "first form" of sets. I want to know if the form of sets which I have used can lead us to another proof.

Comment: @user170039 Your argument shows that $S^+$ and $S^-$ are closed. Now this is a contradiction, because the image of $f$ is connected. Note that your argument is basically a complicated version of the proof that the connected subsets of the real line are exactly the intervals.

Comment: @egreg: I actually didn't know of the result that "the connected subsets of the real line are exactly the intervals". By the way, I don't understand how my argument shows that $S^+$ and $S^-$ are closed. Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: @user170039 If $(f(x_n))$ is a convergent sequence with terms in $S^+$, then $(x_n)$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$, say to $x\in[a,b]$. Then $f(x)=\lim_{k}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_n f(x_n)\ge0$. But $f(x)$ cannot be zero, so $f(x)>0$ and so the limit point of the original sequence is in $S^+$. The same argument as yours about the infimum.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows that $S^+$ is closed.

Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence in $S^+$, convergent to $y$. Our task is proving that $y\in S^+$.

Let $y_n=f(x_n)$; then the sequence $(x_n)$ in $[a,b]$ has a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_k})$. Say that $x$ is the limit point of this subsequence. Then
$$
f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=y
$$
Then of course $y=f(x)\ge0$, but it can't be $f(x)=0$, so $y=f(x)\in S^+$.

It's the same argument you used for proving that $\inf S^+\in S^+$.

Now the set of values of $f$ is the disjoint union of closed sets, so it is disconnected. This is a contradiction.

---

**Note.** Why is this not a good proof? Because it's basically the same proof that the connected subsets of the real line are the intervals. Applying the theorem that continuous maps preserve connectedness, together with the fact about intervals is sufficient for proving the theorem: the set of values of $f$ is an interval containing a negative and a positive value, so it contains also $0$.

You could end the proof without making explicit appeal to connectedness, but you'd be basically reproving the fact about intervals.

Note also that you make appeal to compactness (the Bolzano-Weierstraß property), which is not really necessary here.

Comment: I just read the proof of the result that continuous maps preserve connectedness but the proof I found essentially considers sets of the "first type" rather than the "second". One of the reasons for thinking in terms of the second type of sets was that though (at least, in the case of Bolzano's Theorem) considering the second type of set I could "intuitively complete the proof", I couldn't formalize it. So, I wondered whether a proof using this "second type" of sets could be done.

Answer (score 0):

The following proof is not exactly along the lines posted in the question, nevertheless it doesn't differ radically.

---

Let us consider the sets, $$S^+:=\{f(x):f(x)>0\}$$$$S^-:=\{f(x):f(x)<0\}$$Since $f$ is a function from a closed and bounded set, we can claim that both the sets $S^+$ and $S^-$ are bounded. So $\inf S^+$ and $\sup S^-$ both exists. Now notice that $\inf S^+\ge \sup S^-$. If $\inf S^+=\sup S^+$ then we have nothing to prove. So, assume that $\inf S^+>\sup S^-$.

$\\$Construct the sequence $\bigl(f(u_n)\bigr)_{n\ge1}$ from $S^+$ such that, $$\inf S^++\dfrac{1}{n}>f(u_n)\ge \inf S^+$$ Since $(u_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a bounded sequence, by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem there exists a convergent subsequence $(u_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ of $(u_n)_{n\ge1}$. Let $(u_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ converge to $\alpha$. By Sandwich Theorem $\bigl(f(u_{n_k})\bigr)_{k\ge1}$ will converge to $\inf S^+$.  Furthermore due to continuity of $f$ we have $f(\alpha)=\inf S^+\ge 0$.

$\\$Similarly, construct the sequence $\bigl(f(v_n)\bigr)_{n\ge1}$ from $S^-$ such that, $$\sup S^--\dfrac{1}{n}<f(v_n)\le\sup S^-$$ Since $(v_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a bounded sequence, by Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem there exists a convergent subsequence $(v_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ of $(v_n)_{n\ge1}$. Let $(v_{n_k})_{k\ge1}$ converge to $\beta$. By Sandwich Theorem $\bigl(f(v_{n_k})\bigr)_{k\ge1}$ will converge to $\sup S^-$.  Furthermore due to continuity of $f$ we have $f(\beta)=\sup S^-\le 0$.

$\\$Now, without loss of generality let us assume that $\alpha<\beta$. Consider the interval $(\alpha,\beta)$. Since $f(\alpha)\ge 0$, there exist $\delta_\alpha>0$ such that $z\in (\alpha-\delta_\alpha,\alpha+\delta_\alpha)\cap [a,b]$ implies that $f(z)\ge 0$.
Let $\mathcal{D_\alpha}$ be the set of all such $\delta_\alpha$'s. Then $\mathcal{D_\alpha}$ is non-empty and it is bounded by $\left\lvert a-b\right\rvert$. So $\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha}$ exists. Similarly, we construct the set $\mathcal{D_\beta}$ by taking all those positive $\delta_\beta$'s for which $z\in (\beta-\delta_\beta,\beta+\delta_\beta)\cap [a,b]$ implies that $f(z)\le 0$ and consider $\sup \mathcal{D_\beta}$.

> **Case 1.** If $(\alpha,\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})\cap (\beta-\sup\mathcal{D_\beta},\beta)\ne \emptyset$ , then for all $x\in (\alpha,\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})\cap (\beta-\sup\mathcal{D_\beta},\beta)$ we will have $f(x)=0$. Because, in this case $(\beta-\sup \mathcal{D_\beta},\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})\ne \emptyset$ and so if $x\in (\beta-\sup \mathcal{D_\beta},\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})$ then since $x\in (\beta-\sup \mathcal{D_\beta},\beta)$ we will have $f(x)\le 0$. Also since $x\in (\alpha,\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})$ we will have $f(x)\ge0$. We are thus forced to conclude that $f(x)=0$.
>
> **Case 2.** On the other hand if $$(\alpha,\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})\cap (\beta-\sup\mathcal{D_\beta},\beta)= \emptyset$$ then $(\alpha,\alpha+ \sup\mathcal{D_\alpha})\cap (\beta-\sup\mathcal{D_\beta},\beta)=\emptyset$. So in this case we consider the interval $[\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha},\beta-\sup\mathcal{D_\beta}]$. Observe that $$\forall\varepsilon>0 \exists y\in[\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha},\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}+\varepsilon)\mid f(y)\le 0$$ because otherwise our choice of $\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha}$ is contradicted. So, now construct the sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ where, $$\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}+\dfrac{1}{n}>x_n \bigl(f(x_n)\ge 0\bigr)\ge\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}\tag{1}$$also construct the sequence $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ from $[\min (a,\alpha-\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha}),\alpha+\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha})$ $$\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}>y_n \bigl(f(y_n)\le 0\bigr)>\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}-\dfrac{1}{n}\tag{2}$$ Then both $(x_n)_{n\ge1}$ and $(y_n)_{n\ge1}$ converge to $\alpha+\sup\mathcal{D_\alpha}$. Now notice that from $(1)$ we can conclude that $f(\alpha+\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha})\ge  0$ and from $(2)$ we can conclude that $f(\alpha+\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha})\le  0$. Then $f(\alpha+\sup \mathcal{D_\alpha})= 0$ and we are done.